# HTML base element doesn't append context to head links from JSP tag file

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, url

I am having issues with the HTML base element not appending the context to any link or script URL's. I am dynamically creating the base url within the jsp, and the correct context is set in the source. However, all of the references in the head give 404's in the browser dev console, and the page obviously has no css. I am setting the HTML head with a jsp .tag file. 
Here is my index.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tag" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="uri" value="${req.requestURI}" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="${req.contextPath}" >
    <tag:head page="home" />
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

So I am setting the base as the first thing in the head, and then setting whatever the head.tag file has. I have also tried setting the base in the head.tag file and that doesn't work either. Here is the head.tag file

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="page" required="true" %> 

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<title> <c:out value="${page}" /> </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slide.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/onLoad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/spin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slide.js"></script>
```

So for example, the browser is looking in `http://localhost:8080/css/layout.css` for the layout stylesheet, when it should be looking in `http://localhost:8080/WebApp/css/layout.css`
The base element in the html source when the page renders is `<base href="/WebApp">` which is valid because it is an absolute url and defines the root. I even tried setting the whole url inclidung `http://localhost:8080`
Any ideas as to whats going on here? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The value `/WebApp` is not an absolute URL, and the `href` attribute value in a `base` element must be an absolute URL.

By definition, any URL that begins with the slash `/` is a relative URL. Reference: Internet-standard STD 66, currently [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), clause 4.2.